# How to fix hanging Samsung Galaxy S II phone (GT-I9100)? Also flash and root it?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II model smartphone. GT-I9100 is the exact model number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3skR.jpg), mentioning it since I saw here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II

that there are variants with slightly different model numbers (such as GT-I9100G) and correspondingly slightly different hardware features.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3skR.jpg) That exact model number (GT-I9100) shows both while it boots up, and also when you go to Settings -> About Phone.

(Sorry for the slightly long question, but I have tried to make it as clear as possible.)

A while ago it suddenly stopped booting properly. Before that it was working fine for over 2 years. I had bought it used; not sure if that has anything to do with the problem, but after I first bought it, it almost never had any problem for those 2 or so years, except for one issue: it sometimes used to shut down automatically, without my doing anything. But powering it on again, always resulted in it working normally again. I asked the dealer from whom I bought it, about this issue, and he said it was a known issue in that model.

Now, whenever I power it on, it only goes up to the initial Samsung splash screen (with a big stylized S in the middle of the screen), with the model number GT-I9100 on the right side of the screen, then only the big S for a bit, then again the big S with the words "Samsung Galaxy S II" below it [2], then hangs at the point, indefinitely. Also, while in this hung state (which can only be stopped by removing the battery), it intermittently a) flashes the big S a little brighter, and then b) makes two short beeps. Events a) and b) keep repeating at intervals, of maybe a minute or two. The phone also gets a little heated, maybe due to the big S getting brighter (and then dimmer).

[2] Image of phone in that state is at bottom of this post.

I would like to know how to do the following:

1. Fix it so that it boots fully and works normally. I would like to preserve the data on it, such as contacts, etc., but in the worst case, I'm okay with losing all the data, as long as I can get the phone working again. (I have an older Samsung Android phone which I using as of now, and I had saved most of my important contacts in my Google account, not in the phone or SIM.)
2. I would like to know how to flash and root it, maybe with CyanogenMod or a similar OS. I heard from a friend that by doing that, the battery charge lasts for longer, due to no unwanted apps or services running, apart from the fact that a flashed and rooted phone can be used for more things, such as sshing into a server where I have an account, or getting a Linux console on the phone (which would be cool and useful, even if I could only run a subset of Linux commands).

I will search the net for steps for flashing and rooting it, but would like to know if anyone has any general guidelines for that.

If I need to give any more information for any one to suggest solutions, please let me know.

Thanks.

[image: Image of hanging phone]

Answer (score 2):

1. OK, so for question #1 
   Try to get into recovery mode and then wipe cache partition and dalvik cache - that should help. As I remember, stock recovery is capable of doing that kind of basic things (if I'm wrong - correct me). 
   Basically, you can get to recovery by holding volume down and power button while your phone is off, then release the power button but hold the other one. That should work, if not - check YouTube, I bet guys got the video about how it works with your device.

UPDATE

2. As for second question, I don't really see a point of flashing CM or something similar cause it somehow buggy. My buddie at university has got the same device as you and after all the geeky flashing stuff he decided to go along with rooted stock.

In order to root your device - again YouTube or XDA should help you ;)

Comment: Thanks dnomad, will try out your suggestions and then reply here again on the results. I should have mentioned that I know Linux well as a user and some as a sysadmin (though not done that for a while), so if anyone has any suggestions that involve Unix knowledge, including connecting to the phone from a PC running Linux via a cable to do any troubleshooting (I realize it will have to be after the phone can boot again), please feel free to give such suggestions.

Comment: Well, that makes things a bit easier though. Firstly, check if you have android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot installed. The way to check this is obviously depends on your package manager, in case of debian derivatives with apt-get as Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot. Then connect your device to computer after getting in recovery. From that point you can use some diagnosis tools with adb/fastboot. Anyway, firstly you should try to clear cache as I mentioned before.